# Method not functioning

Tags: java, methods, subtitle

I'm writing a program to fix movie subtitle file(.srt). Putting the code inside the main method works fine but now that I created a method to simplify my code, the method seems not to be functioning and the output is same as input, nothing is being done to adjust the subtitle to and fro time.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class SubtitleFixer
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try{
            File subFile = new File("/sdcard/UCDownloads/video/hichkiSub.srt");
            Formatter fixedSubFile = new Formatter("/sdcard/UCDownloads/video/newhichkiSubFixed.srt");

            Scanner scanText = new Scanner(subFile);
            while(scanText.hasNext()){
                String textFound = scanText.nextLine();
                if (textFound.contains("-->")){

                String fromHour, fromMins, fromSecs, middleText, toHour, toMins, toSecs, endText;
                int adjustMins = 1, adjustSecs = 2;

                    fromHour = textFound.substring(0,2);
                    fromMins = textFound.substring(3,5);
                    fromSecs = textFound.substring(6,8);
                    middleText = textFound.substring(8,17);
                    toHour = textFound.substring(17,19);
                    toMins = textFound.substring(20,22);
                    toSecs = textFound.substring(23,25);
                    endText = textFound.substring(25);

                    fixSubTime(fromSecs,adjustSecs,fromMins);
                    fixSubTime(fromMins,adjustMins,fromHour);
                    fixSubTime(toSecs,adjustSecs,toMins);
                    fixSubTime(toMins,adjustMins,toHour);

                    textFound = fromHour+":"+fromMins+":"+fromSecs+middleText+toHour+":"+toMins+":"+toSecs+endText;
                }
            fixedSubFile.format("%s\n",textFound);
            }
            scanText.close();
            fixedSubFile.close();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException error){System.out.println(error);}

    }

    private static void fixSubTime(String fromOrTo, int adjSecsOrMins, String minsOrHour){
        int fromOrToNum = Integer.parseInt(fromOrTo);
        int minsOrHourNum = Integer.parseInt(minsOrHour);
        fromOrToNum += adjSecsOrMins;
        if (fromOrToNum >= 60){
            fromOrToNum -= 60; minsOrHourNum += 1;
        }
        else if(fromOrToNum < 0) {
            fromOrToNum += 60; minsOrHourNum -= 1;
        }
        formatNum(fromOrToNum, fromOrTo);
        formatNum(minsOrHourNum,minsOrHour);
    }

    private static void formatNum(int num, String text){
        if (num <= 9){
            text = "0"+num;
        }
        else {
            text = ""+num;
        }
    }
}
```

Output (same as input):

> 1
>   00:**01:15**,784 --> 00:**01:17**,994
>   Ma'am, sir will see you now.
>
> 2
>   00:**01:23**,416 --> 00:**01:24**,376
>   Thank you.
>
> 3
>   00:01:43,687 --> 00:01:45,730
>   Ms. Naina Mathur. Please sit.
>
> 4
>   00:01:47,565 --> 00:01:48,942
>   Double Bachelors in Education.
>
> 5
>   00:01:49,317 --> 00:01:51,277
>   And Masters in Science.
>   Impressive.
>   ...

Expected output:

> 1
>   00:**02:17**,784 --> 00:**02:19**,994
>   Ma'am, sir will see you now.
>
> 2
>   00:**02:25**,416 --> 00:**02:26**,376
>   Thank you.
>
> 3
>   00:02:45,687 --> 00:02:47,730
>   Ms. Naina Mathur. Please sit.
>
> 4
>   00:02:49,565 --> 00:02:50,942
>   Double Bachelors in Education.
>
> 5
>   00:02:51,317 --> 00:02:53,277
>   And Masters in Science. Impressive.

Comment: `private static void formatNum(int num, String text){` - this will not work.  Java is pass-by-value.  Try changing this method to return new `String` object

Comment: Yes that's true, I don't know how Java String are passed by reference type but now I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your format method creates a new, manipulated String object, then throws it away. So you'll newer get the result outside of the specific single method call scope.

You need to return the result and accept it in your calling method.

```
private static String formatNum(int num, String text){
    if (num <= 9){
        return "0"+num;
    }
    else {
        return Integer.toString(num);
    }
}
```

Calling needs to be like:

```
fromOrTo = formatNum(fromOrToNum, fromOrTo);
```

P.S.: There is `String.format()` for what your format method tries to do.

Comment: Yeah thanks for that, I didn't keep that in mind. And thanks for the tip also. However, the same bug appears in the calling method (fixSubTime) where I need to manipulate two variables and get their results. Since I can't return two values at the same time, I had to restructure my code.